# convert aws cli output to json format with python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

within the python script i've aws-cli command to print ec2 information

```
def ec2Output = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "aws ec2 describe-instances --region ${Region} --filters Name=tag:Environment,Values=${Environment} --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Version`].Value|[0],InstanceId]'")
 echo "${ec2Output}"
```

then i get the following output from the above command

```
[
    [
        "2023_v1", 
        "i-0xxxxxxxxxx"
        "Dev"
    ], 
    [
        "2023_v2", 
        "i-0xxxxxxxxxx"
        "Dev"
    ], 
    [
        "2023_v2", 
        "i-xxxxxxxxxx"
        "Prod"
    ]
]
```

the question, is it possible that the output can be converted to something like the following
,expected result:

```
{
    "Dev":{
        "Release": "2023",
        "Version": "v1", 
        "ID": "i-0xxxxxxxxxx"

    }, 
    "Dev":{
        "Release": "2023",
        "Version": "v2", 
        "ID": "i-0xxxxxxxxxx"
    }, 
    "Prod":{
        "Release": "2023",
        "Version": "v2", 
        "ID": "i-xxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Python to "call out" to an AWS CLI command, it is better to use the [boto3 library](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_instances.html) to directly make the API call:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

environment = 'foo'

response = ec2_client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'tag:Environment',
            'Values': [environment]
        },
    ]
)

for reservation in response['Reservations']:
  for instance in reservation['Instances']:
    for tag in instance['Tags']:
      if tag['Key'] == 'Version':
        print(instance['InstanceId'], tag['Value'])
```

Comment: i just copied your code and adjust the values but not sure why return error expecting '}', found ':' in the 'Name': 'tag:Environment',

Comment: Perhaps you have some incorrect brackets or commas?

Comment: I have checked which should be correct but somehow this error still appears and I happen to run this Boto3 script on Jenkins pipeline, Is there a possibility that it needs to be adjusted there?

Comment: The error message you provided in the comment above doesn't seem complete. I'm not sure where it got the word `the` in the message.